# Underline transition in menu

Tags: css, focus, css-transitions

I have a menu with a lava-lamp like underline that looks like this:
[image]

The underline slides between links when clicking on them. Try a jsfiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/PnATm/).

My only problem is that if you click outside the menu the underline reverts back to it's original state (18%). But I want the underline to stay on the last clicked link when you click outside the menu.

I've tried `:visited` but it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to do this through CSS, I really don't know.
But why don't you just use these 3 lines of JS (jQuery) and replace the Style-definition by this:

```
$('.ph-line-nav').on('click', 'a', function() {
    $('.ph-line-nav a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

nav a:nth-child(1).active ~ .effect {
    left: 18%;
    /* the middle of the first <a> */
}
nav a:nth-child(2).active ~ .effect {
    left: 43.5%;
    /* the middle of the second <a> */
}
```

Seen in this jsFiddle: [Click me!](http://jsfiddle.net/PnATm/3/)

Comment: I replaced `focus` with `click` and now it works in Chrome too. Maybe you could update your answer with this.

Comment: What does this: $('.ph-line-nav a').removeClass('active'); line do?

Comment: Please read the official documentation: https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/. This is basic jQuery :)

Answer (score 4):

You can actually do this with pure css using The `:target` pseudo class.

Here is an updated <kbd>**[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/SjAwP/1/)**</kbd>

**Note:** You'll need a modern browser to use this method. (IE9+)

Also, take a look at [this article](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/17/css-click-events/) which shows some clever ways to simulate click events with css (one of them being the :target pseudo class.

Comment: I need to target IE7+ but this is good to know for future projects!