# Underline slide transition in buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I tried to search for tutorials on this effect. The effect that I wanted is an active underline (or border-bottom) under a link. When I click on a link, the underline will slide over to the next link and so on... One example is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522835/underline-transition-in-menu).

I know that what I have in html are buttons, not nav menu. So the coding would be different. I'm thinking that I might need to convert the buttons to nav menu if it doesn't work out.

Anyway, the problem is that I did try to use the example mentioned above to make the underline move to a clinked link. But it's not working...

Here's my code which is on [codepen](https://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/YzOVMwr).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $(".con-button").click(function(){
    if(this.id == "c-all") {
      $(".con-button").removeClass("active");
      $("#c-all").addClass("active");
      $('.offline').hide();
      $('.offline').fadeIn("slow").show();
      $('.online').hide();
    $('.online').fadeIn("slow").show();
      $('.none').fadeIn("slow").show();
    } else if (this.id == "c-online") {
      $(".con-button").removeClass("active");
      $("#c-online").addClass("active");
      $('.offline').hide();
      $('.online').hide();
    $('.online').fadeIn("slow").show();
      $('.none').hide();
    } else if (this.id == "c-offline") {
      $(".con-button").removeClass("active");
      $("#c-offline").addClass("active");
      $('.offline').hide();
      $('.offline').fadeIn("slow").show();
    $('.online').hide();
      $('.none').hide();
    }
  })
  
  getSteams();
  
});

var channels = ["BasicallyIDoWrk", "FreeCodeCamp", "Golgothus", "maatukka", "Vinesauce", "brunofin", "comster404", "OgamingSC2"];

  var cb = "?client_id=egn4k1eja0yterrcuu411n5e329rd3&callback=?";

function getSteams() {
  
  channels.forEach(function(indchannel) {
  //for (var channel in channels) {
    //var indchannel = channel;
  var streamURL = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + indchannel + cb;
    
  var channelURL = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/" + indchannel + cb;
  
  $.ajax({
      url: streamURL,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: "jsonp",
      data: {
        //action: 'query',
        format: 'json',
      },
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json",
    },
    success: function(data) {
    
      var game;
      var status;
      
      if(data.stream === null) {
        
        $.getJSON(data._links.channel + "/?client_id=egn4k1eja0yterrcuu411n5e329rd3&callback=?", function(data2) {
          if(data2.status == 404) {
            game = "The Account doesn't exist";
        status = "none";
          } else {
            game = "Offline";
        status = "offline";
          }
          
          $("#offline").append('<div class="indbox ' + status + '"><a target="_blank" href="#">'+ indchannel + '<br/>' + game +'</a></div>');
          
        } );
        
      } else {
        game = data.stream.game;
        status = "online";
        
        $("#online").append('<div class="indbox ' + status + '"><a target="_blank" href="#">'+ indchannel + '<br/>' + game +'</a></div>');
        
      };
      
       
    }
  
  
  });
  });
}
```

```css
html, body{
  height:100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display:block;
}
.container {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 30px auto 0;
  position: relative;
}
.logobox img {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.controls {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.con-button {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
    margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
    padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;
  text-align: center;
    color: rgb(100,65,164);
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: .4s;
}
.con-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  /*border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(224, 217, 236, 1);*/
}
.con-button:focus {outline: 0;}
.effect {
  position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
 .controls .effect {
   /*border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(100, 65, 164, 1);*/
   height: 2px;
    bottom: 5px;
    background: #6441A4;
    margin-left:/*-45px*/auto;
    margin-right:/*-45px*/auto;
   width: 33%;
}
button:nth-child(1).active ~ .effect {left: 0%;}
button:nth-child(2).active ~ .effect {left: 33%;}
button:nth-child(3).active ~ .effect {left: 66%;}
.divider hr {
  border-top: 1px solid #6441A4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="twitchtvarea">
      <div class="logobox">
        <img src="https://s6.postimg.org/bay7stotd/Twitch_Purple_RGB.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="twitchbox">
        <div class="controls">
          <button id="c-all" class="con-button active" type="button">All</button>
                <button id="c-online" class="con-button" type="button">Online</button>
                <button id="c-offline" class="con-button" type="button">Offline</button>    
        </div>
        <div class="divider"><hr></div>
        <div id="online"></div>
        <div id="offline"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I made sure that `.active` is working in Javascript but I still need help making the underline moving from one link to another when clicked. All I know is that it has something to do with the CSS. Any help or tutorials are appreciated.

Comment: Hi,
Checkout this, 

   https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WjEKYx

 I have made changes in your code to make it work.

Comment: Thanks! It works. Please next time, add details of the changes you've made. I had to look and compare each line of the code between mine and yours only to find out that it's important to add `<div class="effect"></div>` in html. Also please add your solution to the answers below. Thank you

Comment: Sure i will take care of it next time. I have added solution to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this simple technique if you can use jQuery. It is quite generic and you can use any html elements whether nav, buttons or simple div's. You just need to have an outer element that contains all your links.

The idea is to find the position and width of the clicked anchor tag and then apply the same(or after adding some modification) to the `underline` element. To make its movement smooth you can add `transition` for `left` and `width` properties of this `underline` element.

```js
$("#outer-container a").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var cssObj = {};
  cssObj.left = $(this).position().left;
  cssObj.width = $(this).outerWidth();
  $("#outer-container #underline").css( cssObj );
});//a click()
$("#outer-container a").eq(0).trigger("click");
```

```css
#outer-container
{
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
}
#outer-container a
{
 color: #333;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#outer-container #underline
{
 content: "";
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 2px;
 width: 100px;
 background-color: #333;
 transition: left 0.3s ease, width 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outer-container">
  <a href="#">One</a>
  <a href="#">Two</a>
  <a href="#">Three</a>
  <a href="#">Four</a>
  
  <span id="underline"></span>
</div><!--#outer-container-->
```

Comment: This sounds wonderful. However, I will have to look in how I can blend this jquery code with my own code. Right now, I'm a bit tired so I will go to bed now and take a look tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $(".con-button").click(function(){
    if(this.id == "c-all") {
      $(".con-button").removeClass("active");
      $("#c-all").addClass("active");
      $('.offline').hide();
      $('.offline').fadeIn("slow").show();
      $('.online').hide();
    $('.online').fadeIn("slow").show();
      $('.none').fadeIn("slow").show();
    } else if (this.id == "c-online") {
      $(".con-button").removeClass("active");
      $("#c-online").addClass("active");
      $('.offline').hide();
      $('.online').hide();
    $('.online').fadeIn("slow").show();
      $('.none').hide();
    } else if (this.id == "c-offline") {
      $(".con-button").removeClass("active");
      $("#c-offline").addClass("active");
      $('.offline').hide();
      $('.offline').fadeIn("slow").show();
    $('.online').hide();
      $('.none').hide();
    }
  })
  
  getSteams();
  
});

var channels = ["BasicallyIDoWrk", "FreeCodeCamp", "Golgothus", "maatukka", "Vinesauce", "brunofin", "comster404", "OgamingSC2"];

  var cb = "?client_id=egn4k1eja0yterrcuu411n5e329rd3&callback=?";

function getSteams() {
  
  channels.forEach(function(indchannel) {
  //for (var channel in channels) {
    //var indchannel = channel;
  var streamURL = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + indchannel + cb;
    
  var channelURL = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/" + indchannel + cb;
  
  $.ajax({
      url: streamURL,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: "jsonp",
      data: {
        //action: 'query',
        format: 'json',
      },
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json",
    },
    success: function(data) {
    
      var game;
      var status;
      
      if(data.stream === null) {
        
        $.getJSON(data._links.channel + "/?client_id=egn4k1eja0yterrcuu411n5e329rd3&callback=?", function(data2) {
          if(data2.status == 404) {
            game = "The Account doesn't exist";
        status = "none";
          } else {
            game = "Offline";
        status = "offline";
          }
          
          $("#offline").append('<div class="indbox ' + status + '"><a target="_blank" href="#">'+ indchannel + '<br/>' + game +'</a></div>');
          
        } );
        
      } else {
        game = data.stream.game;
        status = "online";
        
        $("#online").append('<div class="indbox ' + status + '"><a target="_blank" href="#">'+ indchannel + '<br/>' + game +'</a></div>');
        
      };
      
       
    }
  
  
  });
  });
}
```

```css
html, body{
  height:100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display:block;
}
.container {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 30px auto 0;
  position: relative;
}
.logobox img {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.controls {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.con-button {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
 margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
 padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;
  text-align: center;
 color: rgb(100,65,164);
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: .4s;
}
.con-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  /*border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(224, 217, 236, 1);*/
}
.con-button:focus {outline: 0;}
.effect {
  position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
 .controls .effect {
   /*border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(100, 65, 164, 1);*/
   height: 2px;
    bottom: 5px;
    background: #6441A4;
    margin-left:/*-45px*/auto;
    margin-right:/*-45px*/auto;
   width: 33%;
}
button:nth-child(1).active ~ .effect {left: 0%;}
button:nth-child(2).active ~ .effect {left: 33%;}
button:nth-child(3).active ~ .effect {left: 66%;}
.divider hr {
  border-top: 1px solid #6441A4;
}
.effect {
    position: absolute;
    left: 18%;
    transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.controls button:nth-child(1).active ~ .effect {
    left: 28%;
    /* the middle of the first <a> */
}
.controls button:nth-child(2).active ~ .effect {
    left: 50%;
    /* the middle of the second <a> */
}
.controls button:nth-child(3).active ~ .effect {
    left: 77%;
    /* the middle of the third <a> */
}
.controls button:nth-child(4).active ~ .effect {
    left: 93.5%;
    /* the middle of the forth <a> */
}
.controls .effect {
    width: 55px;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 5px;
    background: #00ABE8;
    margin-left:-45px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="twitchtvarea">
      <div class="logobox">
        <img src="https://s6.postimg.org/bay7stotd/Twitch_Purple_RGB.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="twitchbox">
        <div class="controls">
          <button id="c-all" class="con-button active" type="button">All</button>
    <button id="c-online" class="con-button" type="button">Online</button>
    <button id="c-offline" class="con-button" type="button">Offline</button> 
          <div class="effect"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="divider"><hr></div>
        <div id="online"></div>
        <div id="offline"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have made changes in your code to make it work.